# trigger href with vanilla javascript button instead of html href

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal that is triggered by an html button.  Instead, I want to trigger the modal with vanilla Javascript.  Ultimately I want to trigger the modal with date calculations to remind users of something but that's a battle for a different day.

Right now I would be very happy if I could just trigger the modal with a Javascript function instead of the html button.  I do not want to use jquery, I'm trying to keep things simple and light.

Here's the HTML:

```
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a> 
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog"> 
    <div> 
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a> 
        <h2>Modal Box</h2> 
        <p>This is a sample modal box using CSS3. 
        </p> <p>You could do a lot of things here.</p> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Here's the CSS which is really not part of the question but it was requested.  Why is it not part of the question?  Because the modal works fine...fades in nice...fades out nice...perfectly positioned and responsive.  The question is how to trigger it, so the answer lies in HTML and Javascript, not CSS.

```
.modalDialog {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
     z-index: 99999;
     opacity:0;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
     -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
     transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
     pointer-events: none;
}
 .modalDialog:target {
     opacity:1;
     pointer-events: auto;
}
 .modalDialog > div {
     width: 50%;
     position: relative;
     margin: 10% auto;
     padding: 0.26% 1% 0.6771% 1%;
     border-radius: 0.5208%;
     background: #fff;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
     background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
 .close {
     background: #606061;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     line-height: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     right: -12px;
     text-align: center;
     top: -10px;
     width: 24px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-weight: bold;
     -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
     -moz-border-radius: 12px;
     border-radius: 12px;
     -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
 .close:hover {
     background: #00d9ff;
}
```

Comment: I've requested that you add the css because it is really important to know, that the modal functionality is based on the `:target` pseudo class, which is not really obvious when just looking at the HTML.

Comment: understood, thank you again for providing the example that solved it

Answer (score 0):

You can "mimic" the click from JS function. Simply, get a reference to the anchor element in DOM and perform click event on it. It will behave as if you manually clicked on it.

```
const anchor = document.querySelector('a');
anchor.click();
```

Comment: Thank you but I do not understand.  Let's put it this way:  I am building a site from scratch and 3 weeks ago I opened my text editor and typed "<?php" for the first time.  No offense but I get a little frustrated by half answers like this.  If you could post the whole code, everything that it takes to work it would be more helpful.  People ask questions on here because they don't know what they are doing (myself included).  I am quite sure that if I typed in what you wrote above into the page code it I would get "this page is not working" error...which I get plenty by the way.

Comment: @MikeB, don't worry :). Let me explain it step, by step. Do you know what a reference to DOM is? It is a "link" that connects DOM rendered in your browser with your JavaScript. I believe you have some function that when triggered should display the modal? In order to do so, your JS has to have a connection to said DOM. We can achieve such linking by quering through your page (document). In our query we specify that we want 'a' element. When we receive such reference, we can emit any event on the element as if the user interacted with it. In Your case, we want the click event.

Comment: Thank you, I saved your answer in case I run into something where I need DOM which I have not used yet

Comment: Good luck with further development. You can select one of the answers that all the people have given to mark this question as answered. Upvoting helpful answers is also encouraged as it motivates users to be more helpful. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks.  System says I am too new here to affect public voting.

Answer (score 0):

If the modal works how I think it works (so with pure CSS, which is missing by the way), you should be able to run

```
window.location.hash = '#openModal';
```

to open the modal and

```
window.location.hash = '#';
```

to close it.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/virhonestum/t4upfby3/7/) is a working example.

Comment: @MikeB Please include all the CSS code in your question, and all code that is linked to this, otherwise it's really hard to help

Comment: @MikeB I've addded a working example, see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you!    YES, I got it working with the working example fiddle...thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to "virhonestrum for the answer:

HTML:

```
        <button onclick="openModal()">Open Modal</button>
        <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog"> 
        <div> 
        <a title="Close" class="close" onclick="closeModal()">X</a> 
        <h2>Modal Box</h2> 
        <p>This is a sample modal box using CSS3.</p> 
        <p>You could do a lot of things here.</p> 
        </div> 
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    function openModal(){
    window.location.hash = '#openModal'; 
    }

    function closeModal(){
    window.location.href = '#'; 
    }
```